# Python 2: How to check how many words like 'start' are in my txt file?

Tags: python

I have a **.txt** file called **new_data.txt**:

```
start;pause;stop;pause;start;pause;stop;start;stop;start;
```

How can I write a program that will tell me how many **'start'** words are there in my **new_data.txt** file?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I have looked up this on Google

Comment: And what have you found?

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('new_data.txt') as infile:
    answer = sum(line.count('start') for line in infile)
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `sum([line.count('start') for line in infile])`??? Honest question, not a suggestion.

Comment: Without the brackets, it's lazy -- no list will be built. `sum()` is happy to consume any iterator, not just a list, so it works fine.

Comment: @Stephan: not necessarily. The syntax I'm using returns a generator, which is iterable. `sum` takes an iterable. So this works (on python 2.7+). OTOH, if you were on python 2.6 or previous, you would need the  explicit `[` `]` syntax to make this work. Also, As @kindall says, the lazy syntax doesn't create a list, which means, we can do this in O(1) space, as opposed to O(n) space

Comment: Also, does anyone want to tell me why I got a downvote for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is just a plain text file with **start;pause;stop;pause;start;pause;stop;start;stop;start;** repeated over and over again, just do this:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as f:
    num = f.read().count("start")
```

Note however that this might put a strain on your RAM if your file is very large.  I would only use this for small to moderate size files.

Comment: This would kill your RAM for large files, but would likely be faster than my solution for smaller files